# Trying to integrate mongoDB to Dialogflow with inline editor

Tags: mongodb, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to integrate mongoDB to Dialogflow. More specifically, I'm trying to change the value of a particular data field called 'lightState' in a MongoDB database installed in AWS EC2 instance, by using DialogFlow. When I say 'Turn the light on', the data 'lightState' has to be updated to the value 1 and 0 for the opposite.

Before heading to the real question, I will post my code below:

```
var tunnel = require('tunnel-ssh');
var mongoLib = require('mongodb');
var config = {
    username: 'ubuntu',
    host: <my-host-ip-address>,
    port: 22,
    privateKey: <my-aws-instance-private-key>
    dstHost: '127.0.0.1',
    dstPort: 27017,
    localPort: 24800
};

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
const agent = new WebhookClient({request, response});
console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

var server = tunnel(config, function(error, server){
if(error) throw error;
else {
  if(server != null){
    var Client = mongoLib.MongoClient('mongodb://127.0.0.1:24601/',{useUnifiedTopology:true, auto_reconnect: true});
        var conn = Client.connect(function(error, client){
            if(error) console.log(error);

            function welcome(agent) {
              agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
            }

            function fallback(agent) {
              agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
              agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
            }

      function handleOn(agent)
        {
              const state = agent.parameters.on;
              var doc = {};
              client.db('test_db').collection('light').find().toArray(function(err,docs){
                 doc = docs; //retrieve the data format
              });
              if(state == 1) client.db('test_db').collection('light').update(doc, {$set: {lightState: 1}});  //set lightState to 1 if 'on' state equals 1.       
         }


      function handleOff(agent)
         {
          const state = agent.parameters.off;
          var doc = {};
          client.db('test_db').collection('light').find().toArray(function(err,docs){
             doc = docs;
          });
          if(state == 1) client.db('test_db').collection('light').update(doc, {$set: {lightState: 0}}); //set lightState to 0 if 'off' state equals 1.
          }

    let intentMap = new Map();
    intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
    intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
    intentMap.set('light_On', handleOn);
    intentMap.set('light_Off', handleOff);
    agent.handleRequest(intentMap);         
      });
   }
  }
 });
});
```

Above is the code in DialogFlow's Inline Editor. After deploying the code in the Inline Editor and for the first time I ask DialogFlow to turn lights on or off, everything works fine and the data field in the AWS EC2's mongoDB database changes successfully. But when I try asking Dialogflow to turn lights on/off again, the logs Viewer on Google Cloud Console shows the following error:

```
"Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:24800
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1360:14)
at listenInCluster (net.js:1401:12)
at doListen (net.js:1510:7)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:142:11)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)"
```

I know it means I have multiple processes running on the port 24800. But I don't know how to reuse this MongoDB server continuously on the same port 24800, so that I could ask DialogFlow multiple times to change data in MongoDB. Is there any way for doing this?

---

I tried to initiate the ssh server before onRequest function runs. Here's a small bit of the code to show what I've revised:

```
  var server = tunnel(config, function(error, server){
  exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, 
  response) => {
         ...
```

However it seems that the Inline Editor fails to recognize the function 'dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment', which is associated with the event handler function onRequest. The error log shows below :

```
 2020-05-24 18:44:49.459 JST
 dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment
 Node.js module defined by file index.js is expected to export function 
 named dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment
```

After trying the method above, I came up with the idea of dynamically allocating the port if the port is busy. But I couldn't find anything coming in handy. So I'm stuck for hours trying to find out what could be the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're re-establishing the tunnel to the server inside the `onRequest` handler. This will be done every time your webhook is called without shutting it down, so the address remains in use and the error is thrown.

Better probably would be to setup the `server` when the function is initialized - so outside the `onRequest` handler.

[*update once you tried to setup `server` outside `onRequest`*]
The reason it's telling you that it can't find a function is because you have the `export` statement inside the callback function that `tunnel()` calls. Exports must be done at load time, not when the script is executed

The easiest solution is to **not** have a callback when you setup the tunnel (or to just use it to record success or error). So something like

```
const server = tunnel(config, function(error){
  if( error ){
    console.error( "Tunnel not created: ", error );
  } else {
    console.log( "Tunnel ready" );
  }
});
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = ...
```

should setup the tunnel when the function is initialized.

[*original sidenote*]
You  can also choose to run your webhook on something besides the Inline Editor. If you already have a host where you are running MongoDB, and that host has an HTTPS server with a valid certificate, you can just run your webhook code there.

Comment: Since I could only use Inline Editor in my case, I tried setting up the server before the line exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {,
however the debug log shows an error: Node.js module defined by file index.js is expected to export function named dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment... Is there any reason why the inline editor fails to recognize the function dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment?

Comment: there are several possibilities, but it is better to update the question to note what else you've tried rather than try to put code in comments. Once you've updated your question, comment that you've done so and are still having issues and we can take a look.

Comment: I'm new here, sorry for that. I've updated the question. If you need anything else, please ask me for more infos.